# Javascriptが呼ばれない理由がわからない

Tags: javascript

[javascriptを用いて1~10を選べるプルダウンを作りたい。 - teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/10343)

上記ページを参考に指定したのですが、動きません。console.logも表示されないです。

1. `getElementById("セレクトボックスのID");`を指定
2. `function setSelectMonth()` はselectボックスの `name="selectMonth"` を指定

なぜJavascriptが呼ばれないのか教えていただきたいです。

---

**Javascript**

```
function setSelectMonth(){ console.log("123");
    var selectElement = document.getElementById("Month");
    for(var i = 1; i <= 12; i ++){
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = i;  
        option.innerText = i;  
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>年度</th> 
    <select name="selectMonth" style="width: 40%;" id="select">
    </select> 月<script th:src="@{/js/js}" id="Month"></script></td>       
</tr>
</table></form>
```

Comment: 「getElementById("セレクトボックスのID");を指定」と書かれていますが、javascriptのコードでは「var selectElement = document.getElementById("Month");」となっていて、『<script th:src="@{/js/js}" id="Month">』のIDが指定されています。

Comment: formタグにactionが設定されていない（本来であれば、setSelectMonth()を呼び出すようになっているはず）のが"なぜJavascriptが呼ばれないのか"への回答だと思います。

Comment: action指定はurlだけではなく、setSelectMonth()を呼び出しも可能なんでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これをブラウザで開き、F12で開発モードを開いてConsoleタブから
initializeSlcMonth()
selectSlcMonth(3)
と打ってみてください。

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <select name="slcMonth" style="width: 40%;" id="slcMonth"></select>
    </form>
    <script>
        // ES2015
        function initializeSlcMonth() {
            const selectElement = document.getElementById("slcMonth");
            for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i ++) {
                const option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = i;
                option.innerText = i + "月";
                selectElement.appendChild(option);
            }
        }
        function selectSlcMonth(valMonth) {
            const selectElement = document.getElementById("slcMonth");
            selectElement.value = valMonth;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

動かない理由
select要素のidと、getElementIdに指定するidが違う
（selectタグを操作したいのだから、selectタグのidを指定する）

推奨な書き方１
html内のscriptはbodyの終わりにのみ書きましょう。それ以外は非推奨

推奨な書き方２
scriptのfunction名は、動詞＋○○としましょう
また、get○○、set○○は事実上予約された命名規則です。
（getはvalueの取得、setはvalueの設定です。）

補足
サンプルコード内で、varの代わりにES2015以降の追加文法のconstやletを使用しています。
～iOS9.3.5(iPhone4S、~iPad2)、～IE11では（たぶん）動きません。

Comment: たくさん教えていただきまして有難うございます。

Answer (score 2):

完全なコードを見てないので推測ですが`setSelectMonth`を呼び出していないからでは無いですか.
`function`定義は定義するだけで呼び出しは自動的にされません.

Comment: ありがとうございます、htmlでid指定したものを呼び出しておりますが、動いておりません。これはidメソッドではないのでセレクトボックスのidをしていしましたが、動かない理由がわからないです。

Answer (score 0):

HTMLコードをこれに変更してください:

```html
<form>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>年度</th> 
    <select name="selectMonth" style="width: 40%;" id="Month">
    </select> 月<script th:src="@{/js/js}"></script></td>       
</tr>
</table></form>
```

Comment: 有難うございますm(__)m