# Javascriptが動かない理由がわかりません

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

```
fiscalYear is not defined at Object.<anonymous>
```

というエラーが出てしまいます。このエラーからfiscalYearが読み取れてないと思いました。JSが動いているかconsole.log("123");`で試してみたのですが、出力されないじょうたいです。下記に記載しましたJSの２つをつなげたいのですが、なぜ連動させられないのかがわかりません。教えていただきたいです。m(__)m

### Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="fiscal_year"]').on('change',function(){
        $('select[name="selectyearMonth"] option').remove();
        $('select[name="selectyearMonth"]').append($("<option></option>"));
        if($(this).val() != ""){ 
            for(i=4;i<=15;i++){
                let m = (i<13)?i:(i-12);
                m =('0' + m).slice(-2);
                let y = (i<13)?$(this).val():parseInt($(this).val())+1;
                let op =$("<option></option>",{
            value:y+m,
                      　html:y+"年"+m+"月"
                });
                $('select[name="selectyearMonth"]').append(op);
            }
        }
    });
});


function setSelect(){ console.log("123");
    var selectElement = document.getElementById("setSelect");
    for(var i = 1; i <= 12; i ++){
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = i;
        option.innerText = i;
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

### html

```html
<tr>
    <th>年度 / 年月</th>
    <td>
        <input name="fiscal_year" maxlength='4'> 年 
        <select name="selectyearMonth" style="width: 40%;" id="setSelect"></select> 月
        <script th:src="@{/js/year.js}"></script>
    </td>
```

Comment: 質問の投稿時、まず「言葉による説明」をしてから実際のコードを貼った方が見やすいんじゃないかなと思います。

Comment: setSelect関数の中にconsole.logを記述していますが、setSelectを呼び出している箇所がありませんが、ソースは全てでしょうか？またThymeleafファイルを記述してるのかと思います。フロントエンドの問題であればサーブレット側のHTMLではなくてブラウザで表示されるHTMLを出したほうが解決する可能性が高いと思います。

Comment: こちらはブラウザで表示されるhtmlをのせました。setSelectはjsの機能ではないでしょうか？

Comment: idではselectの指定をしております。

Comment: @keitaro_so さんはJavascriptに記載しているsetSelectを呼び出すアクションがないと仰られています。@123456 さんはどのタイミングでsetSelectが呼び出されると考えておられますか？
あと       document.getElementById("selectyearMonth")
と記載されてますが、selectyearMonthはNAMEなので取得できない挙動をします。

Comment: htmlのid="select"でid指定しましたselectにsetしたいのでsetselectにしましたが、そのid指定しましたselectで呼び出されると考えました。

Comment: selectyearMonthはNAMEなので取得できないということはid指定の場合ですと可能になりますでしょうか？

Comment: `th:src="@{/js/year.js}"`はThymeleaf特有の書き方でブラウザで表示されるときには、置換されてHTMLが出力されるます。質問のHTMLどおりにブラウザで表示されるとしたら何かしら問題が起きている可能性があります。

Comment: setSelectと書くだけでは関数が宣言されただけで何も起こりません。その関数をどこかで呼び出す必要があります。このあたりはjavascript基本です。基礎を学ばないと特定のソースをマージするという作業は難しいと感じます。[JavaScript の基本 - Web 開発を学ぶ | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics)等ネットでもいくつか学習できます。参考にしてください。

Comment: サイトありがとうございます。何がいけないか探してみます。

Comment: htmlのidをsetSelectに変更し、これでjsが該当の関数を取得できるようにできたと考えます。nameは取得できないとのご指摘をいただきましたのでid属性でしていしました。変更したうえで実行してみたのですが、console.log("123");が表示されないです。関数の呼び出しはこの方法はまちがいでしょうか？

Comment: 「nameは取得できない」わけではなく、IDは【document.getElementById】NAMEは【document.getElementsByName】で取得します。@keitaro_so さんも記述してますが関数「setSelect」は記述しただけでは処理は実行されません。あえて参考サイトを提示されていますので”関数　呼び出し”でググったりして頑張ってみてください。それで実行方法がわかります。

Comment: え、そうなのですね。有難うございます！！

Answer (score 1):

[Javascriptが呼ばれない理由がわからない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59020/javascript%E3%81%8C%E5%91%BC%E3%81%B0%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E7%90%86%E7%94%B1%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/)

↑の記載に、さらに典型的なjsの呼び出し方を追記しました。参考ください。
JavascriptとjQueryの文法を理解するのが、遠回りに見えて一番近道だと思います。

サンプル１、htmlの準備ができた時、1回だけ呼ばれる処理を書く書き方。

```
    window.onload = () => {
        // ...
    };

    // jQueryを利用しているなら、細かい差異はありますが、下記でもほぼ同じ意味になります。
    // ※　$()な部分は、jQueryの文法になります。
    $(function(){
          // ...
      }
    );
```

サンプル２、buttonを押したときに、対応するfunctionを呼び出す際の書き方です。

```
<input type="button" value="4月" onclick="selectSlcMonth(4)">
```

以下典型サンプル

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <select name="slcMonth" style="width: 40%;" id="slcMonth"></select>
        <input type="button" value="4月" onclick="selectSlcMonth(4)">
        <input type="button" value="5月" onclick="selectSlcMonth(5)">
    </form>
    <script>
        // ES2015
        window.onload = () => {
            initializeSlcMonth();
        };

        function initializeSlcMonth() {
            const selectElement = document.getElementById("slcMonth");
            for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i ++) {
                const option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = i;
                option.innerText = i + "月";
                selectElement.appendChild(option);
            }
        }

        function selectSlcMonth(valMonth) {
            const selectElement = document.getElementById("slcMonth");
            selectElement.value = valMonth;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

※　別件補足　name属性とvalue属性、class属性、id属性について

name属性とvalue属性は、
inputやselectに使いSubmitすると、サーバーにその内容が送信されます。

class属性は、
cssに対して使用するのが強く推奨されます。
また、一部のjavascriptに対しても使用してもよいです。

id属性は、
javascriptに対してのみ使用するのが強く推奨されます。
（cssに対しては利用するのは現代では非推奨。）